# Simba 2.5.2.1004 ODBC connect oracle 19c to Google BigQuery TABLES was not found in location US {HY000,NativeErr = 31750}

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to connect to BigQuery from Oracle using Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery.
Unfortunately, I am not able to get the data even though the driver test runs correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE9SY.png)

my config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKn6D.png)

I connect from a local instance of oracle 19c via heterogeneous link dg4odbc

Oracle Query:

select * from Tables.most_test@BQ.WORLD;

error in Oracle:

ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Simba][BigQuery] (31750) Dataset is not found. Not found: Dataset metro-bi-wb-pol-im-s00:TABLES was not found in location US {HY000,NativeErr = 31750}
ORA-02063: poprzedzające 2 lines z BQ
28500. 00000 - "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
*Cause: The cause is explained in the forwarded message.
*Action: See the non-Oracle system's documentation of the forwarded
message.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 22

In exel I can see the dataset and table I am trying to read from oracle using the same ODBC driver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EgOf.png)

after changing the configuration based on:

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Simba-ODBC-driver-error-quot-Dataset-xx-was-not-found-in/m-p/488010

like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwFNt.png)

getting:

oracle error:

ORA-28511:lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=%s

but in the trace of heterogeneous link:

[Simba][BigQuery] (100) HTTP Error 400: invalidQuery (Encountered "" at line 1, column 7.
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]). {HY000,NativeErr = 100}
Exiting hgopoer, rc=0 at 2023/07/02-20:34:44
hgoulcp, line 1384: calling SQLGetTypeInfo got sqlstate HY000
Exiting hgoulcp, rc=28500 at 2023/07/02-20:34:44 with error ptr FILE:hgoulcp.c LINE:1384 ID:GetTypeInfo: varchar

and I'm not sure if I'm closer or further from a solution ;)